# How to determine the applications and application id holding locks on a certain table

Tags: db2, db2-luw, locks

I know the command for table holding locks.Can anyone give the command to determine application and application id holding locks for the certain table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the monitor function [`MON_GET_LOCKS()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056428.html?pos=2), for example

```
SELECT lock_name, 
       member, 
       lock_status,
       application_handle 
FROM 
    TABLE (MON_GET_LOCKS(NULL, -2))
```

You can then use [`MON_GET_CONNECTION()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053938.html?pos=2) to retrieve application details by its handle and [`MON_FORMAT_LOCK_NAME()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056427.html?pos=2) to obtain detailed information about a particular lock.